Angular Material mat-chip-list: Error Message Not Displayed When User Types Instead of Selecting from Dropdown
I am currently facing an issue with a mat-chip-list element in my Angular application. The component works as intended, following the approach described in the Angular Material documentation. However, I encounter a problem when users type in values directly instead of selecting from the autocomplete dropdown options.
Issue:
Expected Behavior: If a user types a value that is not selected from the dropdown, an error message should be displayed.
Actual Behavior: The error message is not displayed when users type in their value instead of selecting from the dropdown options.
Setup:
Component: mat-chip-list with an autocomplete dropdown to filter options.
Form Validation: The form should show an error if an invalid value is entered (i.e., not selected from the dropdown).
Issue:
Expected Behavior: If a user types a value that is not selected from the dropdown, an error message should be displayed.
Actual Behavior: The error message is not displayed when users type in their value instead of selecting from the dropdown options.
